# How to set Clang 3.9 as the default in Zesty?

Tags: 17.04, clang

Zesty ships with multiple versions of Clang. The [clang [image: Install clang]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clang) package depends on both [clang-3.9 [image: Install clang-3.9]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clang-3.9) and [clang-4.0 [image: Install clang-4.0]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/clang-4.0). It appears that Clang 4 is used by default:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 4.0.0-1ubuntu1 (tags/RELEASE_400/rc1)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

However, I need Clang 3.9 to be the default version. I am unable to compile UnrealEngine because of this:

```
UnrealBuildTool Exception: ERROR: This version of the Unreal Engine can only be
    compiled with clang 3.9, 3.8, 3.7, 3.6 and 3.5. clang 4.0.0 may not build it -
    please use a different version.
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: Looking through the source code, it just defaults to whatever is in your PATH and CPATH and then does a check on the first version found there. Are you okay temporarily changing those paths to build this?

Comment: @GraysonKent I found an answer and posted it below, but changing the `PATH` would have worked as well, I'm sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791616/set-clang-3-8-as-default) pointed me in the right direction:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install \
    /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/lib/llvm-3.9/bin/clang++ 100
sudo update-alternatives --install \
    /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/lib/llvm-3.9/bin/clang 100
```

After running those two commands, the build was able to continue.

Answer (score 11):

Adding to the accepted answer:

If you have multiple versions of clang, it may be in your best interest to make `clang++` dependent on `clang` so that when you switch to a different clang version and the version of clang++ follows suit.

You can do this using the `--slave` option of `update-alternatives`. So something like this:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-3.9 100 \
   --slave /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-3.9
```

You can of course do it for other versions:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-4.0 100 \
   --slave /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-4.0

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/bin/clang-5.0 100 \
   --slave /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-5.0
```

To switch versions, you just type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config clang
```

Enter a selection and both `clang` and `clang++` will be automatically switched to the same versions.

The same idea applies to `GCC` if you also have multiple versions of that, you can use this method to configure `gcc` and `g++`.

#### Errors:

> update-alternatives: error: alternative clang++ can't be slave of
> clang: it is a master alternative

You may get this error when you try to run the above commands. No worries, it just means that you already configured `clang++` on it's own as an alternative, so you will need to remove that alternative before the above will work. You can do so with the command:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove clang++ /usr/bin/clang++-3.9
```

Do this for each version of clang++, then after removing them all, try again.

#### Sources:

- https://codeyarns.com/tech/2015-02-26-how-to-switch-gcc-version-using-update-alternatives.html
- [How to remove Oracle JDK](https://askubuntu.com/q/117543/145907)